# Combining search criteria

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I have an MVC project with two DropDown-boxes where you can choose from two different lists. In the first list you choose an age and in the second list you chose a name.
Separately, they both work fine. If I choose a name, the view returns all the people with the given name and if I choose age, the same thing happens. The problem is when I try to combine the two lists (dropdowns). Here is the code:

```
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(age) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)))
{
    return View(person.Where(d => d.age == ages));
}
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(age) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)))
{
    return View(person.Where(c => c.name == names));
}
else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(age) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)))
{
    //CODE TO RETURN VIEW MATCHING BOTH CRITERIA
    // For example: IF age is 25 and Name is Bob,  i´d like to display all
    // 25-year olds named BOB...If there is no 25y/old named bob
    // return an empty list
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine `.Where()` clauses and simplify all of this.  Then just build the criteria and have a single `return` statement.  Something like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(age))
    person = person.Where(d => d.age == ages);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    person = person.Where(c => c.name == names);
return View(person);
```

That way any supplied criteria is applied.

Comment: Thats amazing! Worked right away and less code than in my version.
Thanks David!

Answer (score 2):

You can combine conditions with `linq` **where** method

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(age) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
   return View(person.Where(p => p.name == name && p.age == age).ToList());
}
```

This code returns `persons` with name and age corresponding to criteria or an empty list if no result found